# Conversions and Template Type Parameters

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm reading in my book about conversions and template type parameters, and the following is basically confusing the heck out of me (I wrote my questions within the paragraphs that I quoted):

```
"template <typename T> T fobj(T, T);
template <typename T> T fref(const T&, const T&);

int a[10], b[42];
fobj(a,b); //calls f(int*, int*)
fref(a,b); //error: array types don't match
```

"In [this] pair of calls, we pass array arguments in which the arrays are different sizes and hence have different types. [**My question: since when are arrays of different sizes considered different types? Aren't both of these arrays type "int" arrays? What does it mean by this?**] In the call to fobj, the fact that the array types differ doesn't matter. Both arrays are converted to pointers. The template parameter type in fobj is int*. The call to fref, however, is illegal. When the parameter is a reference, the arrays are not converted to pointers. The types of a and b don't match, so the call is in error. [**Question 2: again, how do the types of a and b not match, and why exactly is this call illegal? I'm not understanding]** "

Answer (score 2):

> Q1 since when are arrays of different sizes considered different types?

Since always. What it means is that these two arrays have different type:

```
int a[10];
int b[42];
```

> Q2 how do the types of a and b not match, and why exactly is this call illegal? I'm not understanding

They have different type, explicitly `a` has type `int[10]` and `b` has type `int[42]`. The type can decay to `int*` in certain contexts, such as when passed into functions expecting `int*`. This is what happens in the first function template in the code you quoted. The template gets instantiated into something like

```
int* fobj(int*, int*);
```

So far so good. However, a function taking `a` and `b` by reference would need a parameter list such as

```
int foo( int const (&array1)[10], int const (&array2)[42] );
```

`int const (&arr)[N]` is just the syntax for "`const` reference to a size `N` array of `int`s". A function template that could accept two arrays with elements of the same type but arbitrary size would then be

```
template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M> 
T fref(T const (&)[N], T const (&)[M]);
```

When you instantiate this function with `a` and `b`, you will get a function like `foo()` above.